# Deploy Azure VM based on customize Image available on Shared Image Gallery

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine

[image]

I have first created a simple standard VM in `Azure` which I have customized for data science purpose with different software on it.  Then I have created an image from this VM so that I can deploy new VM based on the customized image faster with same configuration. I have saved the image under `Azure Shared Image Gallery`.
Is it any way to deploy this customized image from a `Terraform` script into a new `Resource Group`? I know how to deploy a normal standard VM from `Terraform` but couldn't find out how to deploy it based on a customized image saved in the Shared Image gallery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To deploy a customized image from  Azure Shared Image Gallery with terraform. You could use [Data Source: azurerm_shared_image](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/shared_image) and [azurerm_windows_virtual_machine](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/windows_virtual_machine) or [azurerm_linux_virtual_machine](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine) to manage it with specify the `source_image_id`. Please note that the newly created VM should be in the **same region** as the shared image before you deploy it. If not, you could replicate this image to your desired region, read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/shared-image-galleries#replication

For example, deploy a Windows VM from generalized shared image:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}


data "azurerm_shared_image" "example" {
  name                = "my-image"
  gallery_name        = "my-image-gallery"
  resource_group_name = "example-resources-imageRG"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "xxxxximageregion"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  admin_password      = "P@$$w0rd1234!"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_id = data.azurerm_shared_image.example.id
  
}
```

**Result**

[image]